# Search a User By it's CNIC Number in .NET 6 MVC Application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a .NET 6 Core MVC App using stored procedures in which when I enter any User's "CNIC Number" then all the records opposite to that user would be displayed.

On the front-end view, the user enters his/her CNIC Number, and all the rows that are related to that CNIC Number are displayed to the user.

A user can have more than 1 debit card registered against his/her CNIC Number in the database. So all the rows that are present opposite to his/her CNIC number would be displayed to the user.

**Database Table:**

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CNIC] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UserName] [text] NULL,
    [CardNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CardStatus] [text] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Procedure:**

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      CyberSoft
-- Description: Get User Info By CNIC
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ABL_GetUserByCNIC]
(
    @CNIC nvarchar(50) = ''
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM UserInfo
    WHERE CNIC= @CNIC
END
```

**UsersContoller:**

```cs
using ABL_USER_DebitCard_Info.Context;
using ABL_USER_DebitCard_Info.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ABL_USER_DebitCard_Info.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        DebitCard_DAL dbcontext = new DebitCard_DAL();
        public ActionResult Details(string CNIC)
        {
            if(CNIC == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                Users user = dbcontext.GetUserByCNIC(CNIC);
                if(user == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    return View(user);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Users Model:**

```cs
namespace ABL_USER_DebitCard_Info.Models
{
    public class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CNIC { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
        public string CardStatus { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**DBContext**

```cs
using ABL_USER_DebitCard_Info.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ABL_USER_DebitCard_Info.Context
{
    public class DebitCard_DAL
    {

        string connectionString = "Data Source = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = ABL_DebitCard_User_Info_DB";

        public Users GetUserByCNIC(string CNIC)
        {
            var user = new Users();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ABL_GetUserByCNIC", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC", CNIC);
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    user.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"].ToString);
                    user.CNIC = reader["CNIC"].ToString();
                    user.UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString();
                    user.CardNumber = reader["CardNumber"].ToString();
                    user.CardStatus = reader["CardStatus"].ToString();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return user;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "opposite to the user"? Also, why are you using the `text` data type? That data type has been deprecated for **17 years**. Do you also need between 8,000 and 2 billion characters to store a user name? I don't think I've ever used an application that would allow me to create over 8,000 character username, and even if I *did* have the option, I wouldn't want to have one that long.

Comment: By "Opposite to that" I mean "all the records with that specific CNIC Number".
What would you suggest as an alternate for "text" datatype?

Comment: `text` was superseded by `varchar(MAX)`, however, as I stated I doubt you need over 8,000 characters for a username, so you should be using an appropriate length (not `MAX`).

Comment: What exactly is the specific question here?

Comment: Got it, will be using that now, thanks for pointing out this mistake too, really appreciate it.
Can you please help me with the search feature?

Comment: The question here is That I want to search all the records that contain a specific CNIC Number

Comment: I think you may be confused by what "opposite" means. Opposite means something that is situated on the other side (of something), or to do something contrary to what was asked. For example, "The chair is opposite the tv", because the Chair and tv are on opposing sides of the room, or "They did the opposite to what I asked them to do."; the person did what you *didn't* tell them to do (perhaps you asked them to put the rest of the books in a box, and they took all the books out of the boxes). "Opposite" doesn't have any meaning in your question here.

Comment: Yes, you are right that's my mistake. I meant to say that I want all the records that contain a specific CNIC Number

Comment: *"I want to search all the records that contain a specific CNIC Number"* Isn't that what your procedure is doing though, @KamranBajwa ? What isn't working here exactly?

Comment: The front-end.
I want to show the user an input field in which when he/she enters the CNIC Number then they'll be shown the Records

Comment: So what about the front end isn't working?

Comment: I don't know how to attach the input field in such a way that when the user enters CNIC Number then it will display data

Comment: So you need to *explain* in your question, where you're stuck, and what you've tried, and what you;re asking, @KamranBajwa . There is no question in the above question, so nothing answerable. "I don't know how" isn't a question.

Comment: Can you please help me with this? I would really really appreciate it.

Comment: Basically I just want to know how to code the view in such a way that it get's user's CNIC that is entered by the user and then display the data from the database